# VGG16 training with colab reutrns WARNING:root:kernel

Tags: numpy, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

im still beginner with DL, here im trying to train VGG16 on a list of images to return `2048` features, but my issue was it returns `4094` features instead of `2048`, so what i did to solve the issue is to create sequential model and remove one layer to be `2048` but will during the training on `google cloab` it returns kernel issue as below :

`WARNING:root:kernel d3b89e05-3e27-4035-afcd-79a2c35a319a restarted`

i have restarted the runtime and make a factorial restart, but still issue exists maybe because I did something wrong I'm my code, this issue happened only in the last code block

```
def read_images(folder_path, classlbl):
       # load all images into a list
        images = []
        img_width, img_height = 224, 224
        class1=[]
        for img in os.listdir(folder_path):
            img = os.path.join(folder_path, img)
            img = load_img(img, target_size=(img_width, img_height))
            class1.append(classlbl)# class one.
            images.append(img)
        return images, class1  
    #compute features for each image. 
def computefeatures(model,image):
   # convert the image pixels to a numpy array
    image = img_to_array(image)
    # reshape data for the model
    image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
    # prepare the image for the VGG model
    image = preprocess_input(image)

    # get extracted features
    features = model.predict(image)
    return features
model = Sequential()


# second convolutional block
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(128,(2,2), strides=(1,1), padding="same",activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2,2))) 

# third convolutional block
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same",activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same",activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2,2))) 

# third convolutional block
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same",activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same",activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2,2)))

# third convolutional block
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same",activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same",activation="relu"))

#DNN Backend
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu')) 

#Output layer for classification (1000 classes)
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='softmax'))

#use the categorical cross entropy loss function for a multi-class classifier.
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# call the image read and 
folder_path = '/content/imageDir/101_ObjectCategories/windsor_chair'

classlbl=0


images, class1 =read_images(folder_path, classlbl)
# call the fucntion to compute the features for each image. 
list_features1=[]
list_features1 = np.empty((0,4096), float)# create an empty array with 0 row and 4096 columns this number from fature
# extraction from vg16 
for img in range(len(images)):
    f2=computefeatures(model,images[img]) # compute features forea each image
    list_features1 = np.append(list_features1, f2, axis=0)
```

Comment: reduce your model parameter, it's more likely you're causing a memory issue and the kernel is force-restarted.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi, sorry but im still beginner can you show me how in the answer section please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most popular reasons leads to restart kernel itself is out of memory (CPU RAM). It seems like because of the read_images function, you were trying to read and store too many image files at the same time.

You may want to try [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/) API for reading images in small batches.

OR

You can simply change your `read_images` function as below:

```py
def read_images(folder_path, classlbl):
       # load all images into a list
        images = []
        img_width, img_height = 224, 224
        class1=[]
        for img in os.listdir(folder_path):
            img = os.path.join(folder_path, img)
            img = load_img(img, target_size=(img_width, img_height))
            yield img, classlbl         ## <--- this line
```

And use it like this

```py
result =read_images(folder_path, classlbl)
# call the fucntion to compute the features for each image. 
list_features1=[]
list_features1 = np.empty((0,4096), float)# create an empty array with 0 row and 4096 columns this number from fature
# extraction from vg16 
for img, _ in result:    # <--- change this line
    f2=computefeatures(model, img) # compute features forea each image
    list_features1 = np.append(list_features1, f2, axis=0)
```

Comment: im still beginner can you show me how please,honestly i have no idea about what kind of change that i need.

Comment: Okay, but can you tell me what the `preprocess_input` function does in your code?

Comment: thank you, i was using normal VGG16 but it generates `4096` features and i was looking to get `2048` features that's why i have implemented this code , and `preprocess_input` as i read it is only to prepare the image for the VGG model

Comment: `preprocess_input` is about to flip, rotate or shift the images right?

Comment: I've edited the answer with some changes, hope it would help you fix the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215603/discussion-between-hai-nguyen-and-jdbc-spring).

Comment: i have applied it but it returns too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: sorry, the last version is quite buggy, try this new one